# Brownian motion (Wiener process) as a random function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

In many articles concerned with functional data analysis, it is considered a regressor $X$ which is a random variable valued in some infinite dimensional set $F$  equipped with (semi/pseudo) metric $d$.

The assumption that $F$  is infinite-dimensional and equipped with (semi/pseudo) metric $d$ makes sense if I think that it is some class of functions (e.g., $C[0,1]$ or $L^2[0,1]$).

**Question** If $X:=W=\{W_t, t\in [0,1]\}$ is the standard Wiener process on $[0,1]$, what the set $F$ should exactly be?

**Comments** Following [Bosq (2000) p.15-16](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1154-9), let $W=\{W_t, t\in T\}$ be a family of random variables defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ with values in a measurable space $(E,\mathcal B)$. In order to interpret  $W$ as a random function, consider the space $E^T$ of mappings from $T$ to $E$ equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal S=\sigma(\pi_t,t\in T)$ where $\pi_t:E^T\to E$ is defined by $\pi_t(x)=x_t $ for $x\in E^T$. Because $W_t^{-1}(B)=W_t^{-1}(\pi_t^{-1}(B))$ for all $B\in\mathcal B, t\in T,$ he inferred that $W$ is $\mathcal A - \mathcal S$ measurable. In this sense, $W$ can be seem as a random function.
Back to my case, it seems that the set $E^T$ of mappings is directly related to the set $F$ thaI mentioned in the begining. (Is $F=L^2[0,1]$?)

I'm not much experienced in this field. Can someone give me directions?

Comment: Are you looking for some space $F$ so that the Wiener process is an element of $F,$ or is your question which $F$ shall be ideally chosen?

Also, do you need to work with Wiener processes, or is it also possible to begin with a functional time series (e.g., an $L^2[0,1]$-valued time series)?

Comment: @Obriareos I'm looking for a space $F$ that is a separable Hilbert space and  $W$ is a $F$-valued random function. I'm focusing on the Wiener process only, because I believe it is the simplest example.

Comment: @Obriareos Unfortunately, with the inner product $<f,g>=\int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$, $C[0,1]$ is not a Hilbert Space.

Comment: $L^2[0,1],$ the space of squared (Lebesgue-)integrable functions with domain $[0,1]$ is the simplest separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @Obriareos Thank you for your attention :D

Answer (score 0):

A stochastic process with continuous paths can be interpreted as a map $$X:\Omega\rightarrow C([0,1]),$$
where $C([0,\infty))$ denotes the set of continuous functions $y:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$.

Now, to properly define a random variable, we need to make both $\Omega$ and $C([0,1])$ into measurable spaces, meaning we need to put a $\sigma$-algebra on $C([0,1])$. To do this, we consider the metric $$d(x,y)=\Vert x-y\Vert_\infty=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|x_t-y_t|$$ and consider the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb B$ generated by the open sets of $d$. Now $$X:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\rightarrow (C([0,1]),\mathbb B)$$ is a properly defined random variable, i.e. a stochastic process with continuous paths.

As you also mentioned, if $T$ is the time-index set and $E$ is the state space of the process, one can also define the random variable on $E^T$. However, this does have some mathematical/topological downsides.

Comment: In Theorem 1.5 of Bosq (2000), it is said that the process $X$ is $L^2([0,1], \mathcal B_{[0,1]}, \lambda)$ random variable, which means it is in a space of  $\mathbb R$-valued random variables such that $(\int_{\mathbb R} \lVert X \rVert^2 d\lambda )^{1/2}<\infty$.